# How to change the default form themes in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: forms, templates, twig, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony 3.2 project and I don't know how to overwrite the default form theme used in every bundle's form. The FOSUserBundle uses a Twig as a templating engine.

As you probably guessed I'd like to achieve that goal without changing any file in `vendor` directory.

Example:

```
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
```

generates the output like this:

E-mail (label)

- This e-mail is already taken. (error)

(text field)

And I'd like to change the way each field is displayed.

Thanks for help

**EDIT**: I found the solution here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html

Comment: Best way is to overwrite the template by extending from the bundle and render the form like you need.